# Can BizTalk 2013 R2 use ADFS Authentication regarding SharePoint 2016?

Tags: biztalk

I know that Microsoft say that BizTalk 2013 R2 is not officially compatible with SharePoint 2016, but is there any way we can configure BizTalk to receive data from a SharePoint 2016 site that requires ADFS authentication? I can't find much information on this (understandably so), but we need a stop-gap solution for this as our SharePoint systems have been updated, but BizTalk is still in the process of being upgraded.

Is BizTalk 2020 capable of this, or should we be looking at doing this another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but it is complicated. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85e72fd8-48c2-4bdb-aa51-8d9c972f4a09/adfs-integration-with-ms-biztalk-server?forum=Geneva

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I assume that is the same for BizTalk 2020? Or does it have better out-of-the-box options for ADFS?

Comment: I haven't seen any mention of  better support for ADFS for BizTalk 2020